# ApolloClient useQuery onError callback doesn't return errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

In my gql call, I'm receiving (200 status code) with errors on my network request.
The response is as it follows;

```
{errors: [{message: "server error message response", locations: [], path: []}]}
```

Here is what I've tried so far?

```
const { data: res } = useQuery(
    GQL_QUERY,
    {
      variables: {
        someData,
      },
      errorPolicy: 'none',
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log('err', error);
        // I want to run function depending on error message
      },
    }
  );
```

How can I get error's message for calling some function on my local? I don't see `console.log` even in on my console.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Might try setting the error policy to `errorPolicy: 'all',`

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling#graphql-error-policies